# Parallelize XML Reading gone wrong

Tags: c#, xml, parallel-processing

I work with **big** XML Files (~2Go), up to now, the reading was done this way:

```
private void readParameters(XmlReader m, Measurement meas)
{
    while (m.ReadToFollowing("PAR"))
    {
        XmlReader par = m.ReadSubtree();
        readParameter(par, meas);
        par.Close();
        ((IDisposable)par).Dispose();
    }
}
```

Which went well, but was slooooow. So I bring my science in, tried to parallelize the reading:

```
private void readParameters(XmlReader m, Measurement meas)
{
    List<XmlReader> readers = new List<XmlReader>();
    while (m.ReadToFollowing("PAR"))
    {
        readers.Add(m.ReadSubtree());
    }

    Parallel.ForEach(readers, reader =>
        {
            readParameter(reader, meas);
            reader.Close();
            ((IDisposable)reader).Dispose();
        }
    );
}
```

But it read the same node in every iteration of the `foreach`. How can I fix this? is this even the good way to parallelize the reading?

Comment: I don't think `ReadSubTree` can be used that way. The [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.readsubtree(v=vs.110).aspx) contain the remarks "You should not perform any operations on the original reader until the new reader has been closed. This action is not supported and can result in unpredictable behavior." and "The ReadSubtree method isn't intended for creating copies of the XML data that you can work with independently. It's designed to create a boundary around an XML element."

Comment: You could try reading the subtree into a new XmlDocument or XDocument and then working on those in parallel, however it is not clear if that would be better or not since we don't know how big the subtrees are or what `readParameter` is doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because, as written in the remarks of [ReadSubtree](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.readsubtree%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> ReadSubtree can be called only on element nodes. When the entire sub-tree has been read, calls to the Read method returns false. **When the new XmlReader has been closed, the original XmlReader will be positioned on the EndElement node of the sub-tree.** Thus, if you called the ReadSubtree method on the start tag of the book element, after the sub-tree has been read and the new XmlReader has been closed, the original XmlReader is positioned on the end tag of the book element.
>   **You should not perform any operations on the original XmlReader until the new XmlReader has been closed.** This action is not supported and can result in unpredictable behavior.

Clearly this method isn't thread-safe. You can't "put aside" some `ReadSubtree()` and then use them later as you are trying to do.

In general, considering that [XmlReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> represents a reader that provides fast, noncached, forward-only access to XML data.

Clearly you can't do what you want. In general because the `Stream` the `XmlReader` is using could be forward-only, so cloning it would require that the `Stream` be "forked" (one "copy" for each clone of `XmlReader`) (something not guaranteed to be possible by the `Stream`) or that the `XmlReader` is caching the nodes (something that is guaranteed not to be done by the `XmlReader`)

As suggested by @mike z, you could

```
List<XElement> elements = new List<XElement>();

while (m.ReadToFollowing("PAR"))
{
    elements.Add(XElement.Load(m.ReadSubtree()));
}

Parallel.ForEach(elements, el =>
{
});
```

But I'm not sure this would change anything, other than your memory use (watch more than 2gb of memory go away :-) ), because now the whole Xml parsing is done in the "main" thread, and all the PAR elements are read in `XDocument` objects.

Or probably you could try:

```
public sealed class MyClass : IEnumerable<XElement>, IDisposable
{
    public readonly XmlReader Reader;

    public MyClass(XmlReader reader)
    {
        Reader = reader;
    }

    // Sealed class
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Reader.Dispose();
    }

    public IEnumerator<XElement> GetEnumerator()
    {
        while (Reader.ReadToFollowing("PAR"))
        {
            yield return XElement.Load(Reader.ReadSubtree());
        }
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}

private static void readParameters(XmlReader m, Measurement meas)
{
    var enu = new MyClass(m);

    Parallel.ForEach(enu, reader =>
    {
        // You do the work here 
    });
}
```

Now the `Parallel.ForEach` is lazily feeded by an enumerator `MyClass` (excuse me for the name :-) ) that will lazily load the subtrees.

Comment: Since 50% of my issue was file reading and the other 50% was about data processing (double parsing, ...) I've put the data processing in another thread and save a **lot** of time. Thanks anyway, I'm less stupid about XML Reader